# Show brings up a list of data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, crud

I am trying to show a list of all the items I've created. (Called "join") In the show.html.erb, I wrote

```
<%= @join = Join.all %>
  <%= @join.each do |join| %>
  <%= join.email %>
<% end %>
```

And It's working, but when I go to the page I get a bunch of data that says: `#<Join::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbca99f12b8> sbhenrichs@gmail.com [#<Join id: 1, email: "sbhenrichs@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-04-30 12:48:16", updated_at: "2016-04-30 12:48:16">]` Does anybody know how to get rid of that?

Comment: Instead of declaring extra `@join` variable and defining that whole block, you could just do `<%= Join.all.map(&:email).join('<br />') %>`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `<%= @join.each do |join| %>` to `<% @join.each do |join| %>`. Ruby code between `<%=...%>` gets parsed by erb processor and outputs html. Generating the html output inside the body of each-do block is fine because that's what we want over here but each-do expression is purely ruby and should be evaluated in `<% ...%>` expression inside html.erb file.

In same context change `<%= @join = Join.all %>` to `<% @join = Join.all %>`. Infact, we should always generate instance variable such as @join inside controller's method instead of cluttering view.

Comment: Additionally `Join` is a pretty terrible name for a model. `Join.joins(:something)` would generate SQL like `SELECT joins* FROM joins JOIN something.id ON joins.something_id`. Which reads like something from a [Dr. Seuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Seuss) childrens book.